# R language tapply with missing values present

Tags: r, tapply

In R, I seek to use the following statement to create a data frame that contains the minimum value of X by ds$Name.

```
MinX <- as.data.frame(tapply(ds$X,  ds$Name,  min))
```

Consider a data set like this:

```
ds$Name     ds$X
Bob          10
Bob           9
Mary         14
Mary          7  
Bob          NA
```

ds$Name contains the same values (e.g, Bob, Mary) of ds$Name multiple times (e.g., there are multiple rows where ds$Name is Bob; there are other multiple rows where ds$Name is Mary).  Thus, I want the minimum ds$X for the Bob records and the minimum ds$X for the Mary records. There is no missing data in ds$Name. In the above example data, the minimum X for Bob is 9 and the minimum X for Mary is 7.

The variable ds$X is an integer and there is some missing data in the ds$X. I seek the minimum value of ds$X by ds$Name while disregarding missing values.

Currently, the result is missing (i.e., NA) for some ds$X when in fact the minimum value of ds$X is a non-missing integer.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Like may of the other summary functions, `min()` has a `na.rm=` parameter you can set to TRUE to remove NA values. See the `?min` help page for more details. Instead, do

```
MinX <- as.data.frame(tapply(ds$X,  ds$Name,  min, na.rm=T))
```